# Is there a composer require-like function to be used to add composer scripts?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, composer-php, jq

I am creating an automated setup for the new projects. This includes creating composer and adding packages etc. One thing that i am strugling right now is how to add the custom scripts to the composer file.

Here i have an example snippet from my `php-init` file:

```bash
#... other scripts...
docker run -it --rm --name sr-composer -v "$PWD"/setup:/app hidden-directory/docker/php/php8.1-code-quality bash -c "composer create-project --quiet --prefer-dist laravel/laravel ." || exit $?
docker run -it --rm --name sr-composer -v "$PWD"/setup:/app hidden-directory/docker/php/php8.1-code-quality bash -c "composer require --quiet --dev nunomaduro/larastan" || exit $?
docker run -it --rm --name sr-composer -v "$PWD"/setup:/app hidden-directory/docker/php/php8.1-code-quality bash -c "composer require --dev brianium/paratest" || exit $?
#... etc...
```

Now, what i want to have is a bunch of custom scripts under generated composer.json file which are gonna be used later on.

Right now, I have something primitive like this:

```bash
#... other scripts...
cp composer.json composer-temp.json
jq '.scripts += {"xc:instanciate": ["php artisan telescope:install","php artisan migrate:fresh"]}' composer-temp.json > composer.json
#... etc...
```

Question - Would it be possible to define a custom script when creating a composer project, similar like you have `composer require <package_name>`? I was searching through web / documentation etc, couldn't find what i was looking for.

Or should i stick with the `jq` `composer.json` file manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way. There is a composer command `composer config`.

I used the following:

```bash
composer config --json scripts.xc_instanciate "php artisan telescope:install" "php artisan migrate:fresh"
```

Which added to my `composer.json` the following:

```json
{
   ...
   scripts: {
      ...
      xc_instanciate: [
         "php artisan telescope:install",
         "php artisan migrate:fresh"
      ]
   }
}
```

It has some limitations, but it does what i needed!